# Check if 2 users are in the same room with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user_to_room table

```
roomID | userID
```

I now want to check, if 2 users are in the same room

```
SELECT roomID
FROM   room_to_user
WHERE  userID = 1 AND 2
```

How to achieve this with a JOIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.roomID AS roomID
FROM   user_to_room u1, user_to_room u2
WHERE  u1.userID = 1 AND u2.userID = 2
AND    u1.roomID = u2.roomID;
```

See [**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f84de/5).

Comment: Where do I have to put in my 2 userIDs?

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I need to get the roomID of two given users. Right now it just returns all roomIDs with more than one user?

Comment: @Chris Your question does not clearly states that you want the roomid for two specific user. You asked "if 2 users are in the same room".

Comment: Yeah but with given user ids (thats why I put 1 and 2 there) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE user_to_room (roomID INT, userID INT);

INSERT INTO user_to_room VALUES (101, 2);
INSERT INTO user_to_room VALUES (102, 3);
INSERT INTO user_to_room VALUES (102, 4);


    select distinct roomid 
from user_to_room a where exists 
(select top 1 1 from user_to_room where roomid = a.roomid and userid =3)
and userid = 4
```

check the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46afa/3) here

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can use is this:

```
SELECT   roomID
FROM     user_to_room
WHERE    userID IN (2,3)
GROUP BY roomID
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT userID)=2
```

This will count the number of DISTINCT users for each room that satisfy the condiction `userID IN (2,3)`. If the count is 2, it means that both userID 2 and userID 3 are in the same room.

Comment: I just tried it, but it returns more than one roomID. It return all roomIDs which are both users in, even if there are other users in the room too.